# choosing 5 random numbers / coordinates on a grid in python

Tags: python

I need help with making this so I can convert a string into a number in a list, I have done this but if I wanted to do it this way I would have to wright a dictionary with 100 definitions which I do not want to do. The code is just to show what I found all ready. As you can see this would take 100 definitions if I were to do it this way.

```
x1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x4 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x5 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x6 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x7 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x8 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x9 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x10 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

my_dict_grid = {
  'x2[3]' : x2[3]
}

x = 'x2[3]'

print(my_dict_grid[x])
```

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? There's probably an easier way of you take a step back...

Comment: I am trying to make something that generates 5 completely random numbers on a 10x10 grid made up of 0's. then change the random coordinates values to 1.

Comment: You probably want to store the whole grid in one variable, either a list of lists or a numpy array; then you'll be able to index it as `x[i][j]` or `x[i, j]` (respectively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple arrays you are managing all at once, create a multi-dimensional array:

```py
x = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

In that case, you can just index by row then column:

```
x[2][3]
```

Based on your comment, you want to randomly change values in the array. In that case, the approach above is not at all what you want. You want to pick two random numbers, and index to them in `x` to change them:

```
import random

for _ in range(5):
    updated = False
    while not updated:
        i = random.randrange(10)
        j = random.randrange(10)
        if x[i][j] == 0:
            x[i][j] = 1
            updated = True
```

### Original answer to the initial question:

(this is here more as an interesting thing, not as a viable approach)

Okay. Assuming that you have to do it the way you have described, you can generate a dictionary with all of the string keys:

```py
my_dict_grid = {
   f"x{i + 1}[{j}]": arr[j]
   for i, arr in enumerate([x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10])
   for j in range(10)
}
```

However, I have to stress that this is not a good idea.

Comment: thank you very much, I am fairly new to python could you roughly explain the first piece of code, the second I can understand but not the first.

Comment: Yes. Don't use the first. You should never try to index into an array with a string the way you have described it...

Comment: As I see it, it is not guaranteed that 5 entries are set to 1, as the same indices can be chosen multiple times.

Comment: That is correct. But I have updated the logic so that it always updates a value. However, this approach will become less and less efficient the more values you have, and will enter an infinite loop, if all values are 1!

Answer (score 1):

3 different ways to solve this with oneliners, depending of the output you want:

```
my_list = [[ 0 for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
my_dict = {"x"+str(i+1):[ 0 for _ in range(10)] for i in range(10)}
my_dict2 = {"x"+str((i+1)%10)+"["+str(int((i+1)/10))+"]": 0 for i in range(100)}
print(my_list) #[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
print(my_dict) #{'x10': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'x9': [0,...
print(my_dict2)#{'x4[3]': 0, 'x1[9]': 0, 'x6[6]': 0, 'x2[8]': 0,...
```

Answer (score 0):

A more mathematical, but very practical way to do this with numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
grid_shape = [10, 10] # define 10 x 10 grid
num_ones = 5
cells = np.zeros(grid_shape[0]*grid_shape[1]) # define 10*10 = 100 cells as flat array
cells[0:num_ones] = 1 # Set the first 5 entries to 1
np.random.shuffle(cells) # Shuffle the entries, such that the 1's are at random position
grid = cells.reshape(grid_shape) # shape the grid into the desired shape
```

Running the code above and will e.g. result in grid=

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Note that, by changing grid_shape you can resize your grid, and by changing num_ones, you will adapt the number of ones in your grid. Also, it is guaranteed that there will always be num_ones ones in your grid (given that num_ones is smaller or equal the number of elements in the grid).